# Mongodb and MapReduce - results missing

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

with this code:

```
var map = function(){

    emit(1, { read: this.read, important: this.important, count: 1 })
}

var reduce = function(key, vals) {

    var i = 0, r = 0, c = 0;

    vals.forEach(function(d) {
       r += !d.read ? 0 : 1;
       i += d.important ? 0 : 1
       c += d.count;
    });

    return { read: r, important: i, count: c }
}

db.ipdr.mapReduce(map, reduce, { out: "__mr_test", verbose: true, query: { liid: "40001" } });
db.getCollection("__mr_test").find();
```

I get incomplete count:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "value" : {
        "read" : 1,
        "important" : 7,
        "count" : 7607
    }
}
```

"count" is OK, but "read" and "important" should be a lot higher. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a good usage of mapReduce. The aggregation framework uses native code which is much faster than JavaScript execution and can do the same job. Assuming "read" and "important" are logical values that is:

```js
db.posts.aggregate([
    { "$sort": { "read": 1, "important": 1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "read": { "$sum": { "$cond": [ "$read", 1, 0 ] } },
        "important": { "$sum": { "$cond": [ "$important", 1, 0 ] } },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

So not only faster but much more simple to code.

Given the sample documents:

```js
{ "read" : true,  "important" : false }
{ "read" : true,  "important" : false }
{ "read" : false, "important" : false }
{ "read" : false, "important" : true  }
{ "read" : true,  "important" : true  }
```

The result would be:

```js
{ "_id" : null, "read" : 3, "important" : 2, "count" : 5 }
```

Comment: I hope that works, but looks uglier with all these "$" chars. :) Isn't agg. framework using mapreduce under the hood?

Comment: @dakt No it is natively implemented in C++ code directly. mapReduce uses a JavaScript interpreter ( v8 in modern versions ). All the `$` symbols are how the aggregation framework defines it's operators and variables referring to fields in order to distinguish them from valid field names, which cannot start with a `$` for the obvious reason.

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment. I was so sure that AF was driven by MapReduce. So it should be completely avoid?

Comment: @dakt There are actual valid reasons why mapReduce should be used, or otherwise must be used at present for particular problems. All I was pointing out as part of the answer is that where a better alternative exists, then use it. Since the aggregation framework was a later introduction it is very possible there are legacy uses that can be better achieved with the aggregation framework.

Comment: @dakt I gave a small edit along with an working example. Even if you are away from your actual data there should be no reason not to accept.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
r += !d.read ? 0 : 1;
i += d.important ? 0 : 1
c += d.count;
```

Shouldn't you be having

```
r += !d.read ? 0 : d.read;
i += d.important ? 0 : 1
c += d.count;
```

Comment: Now I get correct result for "read", but when I remove "!" I get 0 which is not correct....

Comment: If you could provide a sample data and expected output then it could answered in a better way, However please take a look at aggregation framework as well. It's faster and much better.

Comment: Just assume that every document contains: { read: Boolean, important: Boolean } among may other fields.